# Openliberty with java11 has warnings

Tags: java, websphere-liberty, java-11, open-liberty

I used OpenLiberty version 19.0.0.4 with JavaEE 8 on JRE runtume version 11 .
when i running application server , receive this warnings :

```
[WARNING ] CWWKS3103W: There are no users defined for the BasicRegistry configuration of ID com.ibm.ws.security.registry.basic.config[basic].
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadContextAccessor (file:/opt/wlp/lib/com.ibm.ws.container.service_1.0.27.jar) to field java.lang.Thread.contextClassLoader
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadContextAccessor
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

How can fix this ?

Comment: It's a warning, so there's nothing to fix per se. Just heed those warnings (except don't bother reporting it to the maintainers, they're most likely very aware of that).

Comment: Okey , Thank you

Comment: Thread defines setContextClassLoader and getContextClassLoader methods so surprising that it tries to access the private field directly. As always, it's way too fragile for anyone to be depending on private fields of classes in the JDK as they could change at any time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug in OpenLiberty, see [open-liberty#7180](https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/issues/7180)

According to the bug setting `JAVA_HOME` will fix the issue.

Comment: It appears that a fix was put in for unix platforms at least in a later version of OpenLiberty.  The issue mentioned above has a PR that references it.